# Bounds on difference in L-smoothness across batches

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Consider a neural network parameterized by $w$ and taking in data samples in mini-batches $x \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times d}$, and its twice-differentiable loss function $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$. Consider a training dataset $X_{train} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times d} \sim \mathcal{D}$, from which i.i.d. mini-batches can be drawn, and a loss value for the minibatch $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}^k$ can be computed. Suppose we draw two sets of mini-batches drawn i.i.d from $X_{train}$, say $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$, such that $\lvert \mathcal{X} \rvert = \lvert \mathcal{Y} \rvert = m$ and $\bigcup \mathcal{X} = \bigcup \mathcal{Y} = X_{train}$. Then, is it possible to get a bound on the maximum difference in $L-$smoothness across the two sets, i.e.

$$
\max\limits_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \lVert \nabla_w^2 f(x) \rVert - \max\limits_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} \lVert \nabla_w^2 f(y) \rVert
$$

Edited to add: for each $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$, I have closed-form solutions to $\max \lVert \nabla^2 f \rVert$, and I intend to use them.